# setResult not returning expected result, when using with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

Calling activity code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BuyActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, BuyActivity.BUY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Calling activity result handler:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("billing","Got response from buy activity. resultCode = " + requestCode);
        if(requestCode== BUY_REUEST_CODE){
            boolean buyStatus= data.getBooleanExtra(BuyActivity.BUY_STATUS, false);
            if(buyStatus){
                Log.d(Constants.APP_TAG,"purchase was successful");
                enablePaidFeaturesIfRequired();
            }
            removeAdsIfRequired();
        }
    }
```

Called activity code:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra(BUY_STATUS, false);
Log.d(APP_TAG,"Setting buy activity result to " + RESULT_OK);
BuyActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Am not getting RESULT_OK in the handler, even when i see that following in logs

```
 "Setting buy activity result to -1 ";
```

Rather am getting result as 1 which is RESULT_FIRST_USER,

Comment: You're looking at the wrong parameter: `requestCode== RESULT_OK`. Your `requestCode` was `BuyActivity.BUY_REQUEST_CODE`. You want to check `resultCode` for `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: I changed that, irrespective of that, The log statement on first line shows that result 1 is returned instead of -1. "Got response from buy activity. resultCode = 1"

Comment: Did you change the log print, too? Your code shows you're printing `requestCode`, not `resultCode`.

Comment: Ah, That was the issue. Sorry about that. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `if(requestCode== RESULT_OK){` to `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){`

In the log, there is a typo `resultCode = " + requestCode`. the `resultCode` and `requestCode` are different.

Comment: Fixed that, irrespective of that, The log statement on first line shows that result 1 is returned instead of -1. "Got response from buy activity. resultCode = 1"

Comment: There is also a typo in the log statement. I've updated my answer.